# Pipe all email sent by an authenticated connection to an external script and still deliver it to the recipient

Tags: postfix

Using Postfix I want to pipe all messages sent by an authenticated connection to an external script and still deliver it to the recipient. Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: Thank you all for your coments. I can pipe all messages to a script defining a new transport in "master.cf". My problem is that I want to deliver the mail to the recipient at the same time. It should be possible but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably after a Sendmail milter (mail filter), which is a program that Postfix will pass all incoming mail to for filtering. You can write these in C, Python or Perl with the various libraries available.

If you don't want to write your own, you can try hooking in using [milter-cli](http://www.snertsoft.com/sendmail/milter-cli/)'s `content-filter` option - this allows you to pipe all mail to an external script. Make sure your script always returns 0 to force delivery.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to do that by installing MIMEDefang and extending mimedefang-filter.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the sender/recipient or can accept having all mail copied you can try the always_bcc[1](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#always_bcc), recipient_bcc_maps[2](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_bcc_maps) and sender_bcc_maps[3](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#sender_bcc_maps) options. Then have procmail or similar for the destination mailbox feed your script.